# Forest plot using risk ratio and confidence intervals

Tags: r, r-forestplot

How to make forest plot like this using risk ratio and confidence intervals with the comparison labels?
I don't want R to automatically group the comparison, I just want to plot the forest plot with the labels at the left hand side. Thank you.

I use this code:

```
d=result
df=data.frame(d)

cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = df$RiskRatio, 
    lower = df$LowerLimit,
    upper = df$UpperLimit),
    .Names = c("RiskRatio", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -14L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c(df$Outcomes),
  c(df$Comparison),
  c(df$...4),
  c(df$RiskRatio))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
           clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

but it shows error

Comment: Is this what you mean: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html#positioning-the-graph-element ? I.e. if you're using `forestplot()` specify `graph.pos = 2`

Comment: @jared_mamrot I tried the code above but its not working

Comment: I have added in the code and data as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
#install.packages("forestplot")
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("",
    "Comparison",
    "Placebo 1",
    "Placebo 2",
    "Placebo 3",
    "Placebo 4",
    "Placebo 5",
    "Treatment 1",
    "Treatment 2",
    NA,
    ""),
  c("",
    "Relative Risk \n 95% CI",
    "0.88 (0.84-0.92)",
    "0.87 (0.81-0.94)",
    "0.88 (0.84-0.92)",
    "0.87 (0.81-0.94)",
    "0.88 (0.84-0.92)",
    "0.88 (0.84-0.92)",
    "0.87 (0.81-0.94)",
    NA,
    "0.87 (0.81-0.94)"),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"),
  c("", "F", "1.1", "1.3", 
    "0.2", "5", "3.1", "0", 
    "0.1", NA, "4.1"))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,
           graph.pos = 3, 
           new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(rep(FALSE,11)),
           clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE,
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",
                        line="darkblue",
                        summary="royalblue"))
```

[image: forestplotdemo]

Comment: Yes, but I always get Error in forestplot(tabletext, cochrane_from_rmeta, new_page = TRUE, is.summary = c(TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (new_page = TRUE, is.summary = c(TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE, 8), TRUE), clip = c(0.1, 2.5), xlog = TRUE, col = fpColors(box = "royalblue", line = "darkblue", summary = "royalblue"))

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, the solution is what you're trying to get but if you cut and paste the code in my answer you get an error? Are you pasting it into R console or Rstudio? Are you running it all together or command-by-command? Can you please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question?

Comment: Hi Jared, I realized my font was too big, once I added `txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex=.5)` and changed `is.summary=c(rep(FALSE,11))`, it works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If my solution is sufficient, please [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)